# Composer hook to fix package version

Tags: php, composer-php

I need to hook in composer installation process to fix versions of second level dependencies of root package. I.e. my package depends on some packages (with correct versions) but these packages depends on other packages and its versions are "wrong". I try to use **pre-package-install** hook to patch such versions but it is not working for me, code inside Installer::prePackageInstall is not executed.

Root package composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "***/root-package",

    "repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "http://***/packages.json" } ],

    "require": {
        "***/first-level-dep-1": "dev-release-XX",
        "***/first-level-dep-2": "dev-release-XX"
    },

    "scripts": {
        "pre-package-install": [
            "root-package\\Installer::prePackageInstall"
        ]
    }
}
```

First level dependency composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "***/first-level-dep-1",

    "repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "http://***/packages.json" } ],

    "require": {
        "***/second-level-dep-1": "*",  // !!! here is my problem
        "***/second-level-dep-2": "*"
    }
}
```

I need to replace ***** to appropriate version during installation process.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "fix" that version. You should simply add that second-level-dep as your own dependency in the correct version, and the case is solved.

If the first-level-dependency requires ANY version of that package, then YOU depending on the correct version will restrict the installable versions to the one you allow.

Comment: If I add all second (and more) level deps as my own deps I will lost all advantages of using composer deps management. And here * does not means "any version". In our case it means "replace me on correct version" depending on in e.g CI building branch. When CI clones target package and start building them it replaces * in root package composer.json and expects that all second level deps version also will be replaced. But such approach does not work anymore. On the same time we can explicitly commit "version == release branch" in every package but it is a lot of work resolving vcs conflicts.

Comment: Then your problem is not correctly explained. If you have any system that is expecting the version "*" to be replaced by the CI process with the correct version, please add the details into your question. I would however already say that you will still loose all advantages of Composer deps management, because I would expect all package to define their versions based on their software feature needs. I am a huge fan of using tilde version requirements and sticking to semantic versioning. That way any package can state the MINIMUM version needed, but allowing for any updated version possible.

Comment: You are right, I should update question. In addition we already find approach to patch version through composer package installation hooks. I describe it here on weekend. Thank you!